# javascript for loop in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, for-loop

Here's my view :

```
$(".qty").keyup(function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var bt = (this.id);
    var bts = $('#bts'+bt).val();
    var edge = $('#edge'+bt).val();
    for (var i = 1; i<edge; ++i) {
        var batas = $('#bts'+i).val();console.log(batas);
    }
});


<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo 'edge'.$items['id']?>" value="<?php echo $items['options']['jum']?>"/>
<?php
foreach ($items['options']['stok'] as $stok) {
    $er = $stok['stokbagus'];
    $length = $items['options']['jum'];
    for ($i=1; $i< $length; $i++) {
        echo '<input type="text" rel="'.$items['rowid'].'" id="bts'.$i.'" value="'.$er.'"/>';
    }
}
?>
```

`$items['options']['jum']` contains  = 2.

`$stok['stokbagus']` contains = 30 and 21.

It'll display the first one (30). How to display all  `$stok['stokbagus']` in javascript?
Because i want to compare `$(".qty").val()` with all of  `$stok['stokbagus']`

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here is what you should do.

If your $stok['stokbagus'] variable is array, then you should select the first and the second variable like this:

```
$first = $stok['stokbagus'][0];
$second = $stok['stokbagus'][1];
```

Else if, your $stok['stokbagus'] variable is a string and has 30,21 like this;

```
$vars = explode(",", $stok['stokbagus']);

$first = $vars[0];
$second = $vars[0];
```

You are saying that $stok['stokbagus'] variable has 30 and 21 values then it must be an array.

To show all values in your $stok['stokbagus'];

```
implode(', ', $stok['stokbagus']; // or just use $er.
```

Full:

```
echo '<input type="text" rel="'.$items['rowid'].'" id="bts'.$i.'" value="'.implode(', ', $er).'"/>';
```

---

Update:

```
<?php
foreach ($items['options']['stok'] as $stok) {
    $er = $stok['stokbagus'];
    $length = $items['options']['jum'];

    for ($i=1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if(is_array($er)) {
            foreach($er as $key => $value) {
                echo '<input type="text" rel="'.$items['rowid'].'" class="bts"  data-id="'.$i.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<input type="text" rel="'.$items['rowid'].'" id="bts'.$i.'" value="'.$er.'"/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Js:

```
$(".qty").keyup(function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var bt = (this.id);
    var bts = $('#bts'+bt).val();
    var edge = $('#edge'+bt).val();

    for (var i = 1; i<edge; ++i) {
        // I don't know what do you want to do with batas variable...

        if($('.bts').length > 1) {
            $('.bts').each(function(){
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
        } else {
            var batas = $('#bts'+i).val();console.log(batas);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: yes, it's an array. but, if i know the contain of $items['options']['jum']  are 2, i'll add [0] and [1]. what if the contain of $items['options']['jum'] are 3 or 4 or 5? because all of that integrated with database.

Comment: Look now. Just use implode. I have updated my answer.

Comment: sorry,I didnt explain it more detail. my point is i want to display $stok['stokbagus'] in javasript because it only appears in the first one (30) --> var batas = $('#bts'+i).val();
did i make mistake with my looping in javascript?

Comment: If your $stok['stokbagus'] has an array value (the type of the variable === array) you can not echo that variable without a seperator / glue method. Firstly you have to tell me: "What is your $stok['stokbagus'] variable's value (what is it holding)". If it has 30 and 21 as different child values, as i said before, you have to use one of the methods that i give you in example. Your javascript seems good to me.

Comment: now, i know the problem. when i click view page source in my browser. it display like this <input type="text" id="bts1" class="batastok" value="30"/><input type="text" id="bts1" class="batastok" value="21"/>
with same id. how make 21 into a different id ?

Comment: If you have more then one element that has "bts1" id, it's normal to get the first one. Try to change id attribue to class and put them in an each loop. But what is your goal? Do you want to get 30 and 21 in different variables or like 3021?

Comment: Ok that was the last update that i did for you. You are not clear enough, sorry.